# How to apply a type definition in a template literal during looping?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am looping through a list of objects (given below)

```
let links = [
    {
        name: 'Services',
        children: [
            {
                service1: 'First service',
                caption: 'We provide a full range of audit and assurance services to a wide range of clients',
            },
           {
               service2:'Second service',
               caption: 'Second caption'
            }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

To access the service1 and service2, I use index during the looping such that `` children[`service${index+1}`] `` Typescript shows the error that Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type

```
`service${number}`
```

can't be used to index.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The `children` value is an array, so the entries of the array (the objects with the "service" properties) will be indexed as 0, 1, ...

Comment: Thus `links[0].children[1]` will give you the "service2" object.

Comment: "*expression of type `service${number}` can't be used to index.*" - you haven't show us what the inferred type of `children` was. Did you declare the type of `links` properly?

Comment: He probably also has a data structure problem as it's kind of weird they have different key names `servive1` and `service2` (but dont know enough about use case).

Comment: You really shouldn't be using different property names for the service parts of your objects. Just call them all  `service`! Why are you making it so complicated? Fix the problem at the root, where this weird object is created.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I changed it to service.

Comment: You can maybe specify the children object as something like this `children:[[key:string]:string]` and the rest is just basically the type you give the object it self